# How to sync with online json beucase offline sqlite get populated with duplicate entries?

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I was working on a notification system which grabs data using volley and save it in the offline db(sqlite) and shows it via listview so users can see the notification on offline the problem is that I was able to get last entered notification properly .

```
$query="SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM tnews ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3) sub ORDER BY id ASC";
```

but when I try to insert it into offline db it gets populated . Is there any way to get the same in the offline db too there will be only 20 or 30 entries but when it duplicates its taking some more space i don't what that does clearing the table each time solve my problem?
Code for insertion

```
public void addContact(String id,String date,String time,String news,String valid) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      // values.put(KEY_ID,id ); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_DATE,date); // Contact Phone
        values.put(KEY_TIME,time ); // Contact Phone
        values.put(KEY_NEWS,news);
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        //values.put(KEY_VALID,valid);
        //Log.d("Insering",id);
        Log.d("Insering",date);
        Log.d("Insering",time);
        Log.d("Insering",news);
       // Log.d("Insering",valid);


        // Inserting Row

        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

The id name in both sides are identical and they are primary also . Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before inserting data into your database you have to check first is data exists or not in your local database, if exists then need to update row or need to insert row into database, check this:

```
             public void addContact(String id,String date,String time,String news,String valid) {
                    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    // values.put(KEY_ID,id ); // Contact Name
                    values.put(KEY_DATE,date); // Contact Phone
                    values.put(KEY_TIME,time ); // Contact Phone
                    values.put(KEY_NEWS,news);
                    if(!isRecordExists(KEY_ID,TABLE_CONTACTS,id)) {
                        values.put(KEY_ID,id );
                        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
                    }else{
                        // if you want to update row then only uncomment below line
                        // db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{id});
                    }
                    //values.put(KEY_VALID,valid);
                    //Log.d("Insering",id);
                    Log.d("Insering",date);
                    Log.d("Insering",time);
                    Log.d("Insering",news);
                    // Log.d("Insering",valid);


                    // Inserting Row

                    db.close(); // Closing database connection
                }

                public boolean isRecordExists(String columnName, String tableName, String id) {
                    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                    if (!db.isOpen()) this.onOpen(db);
                    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + tableName + " where " + columnName + "=?",
                            new String[]{id});
                    boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
                    cursor.close();
                    return exists;
                }
```

Comment: Let me give it a try